# Are these two sorting format exactly the same for dict sort in Python?

Tags: python

```
x = {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
    print(x.keys())
    s1 = [item[0] for item in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0]), reverse=True)]
    s2 = [item[0] for item in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)]
    print(s1)
    print(s2)
```

The prints are:

```
dict_keys([1, 3, 4, 2, 0])
[3, 4, 1, 2, 0]
[3, 4, 1, 2, 0]
```

I usually use the 2nd way to sort a dict by value, but today I saw someone's else code to sort a dict using the first way.

Are they exactly the same thing? They look the same based on print outs.

Comment: Try `x = {1: 0, 2: 0}`. With this input, the results are _guaranteed_ to be different for python 3.7+.

Comment: So what's the difference?

Comment: The first one sorts the dict also by the key (in descending order), when there is a tie based on the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the results are identical because there is a bijection between the set of keys and the set of values. If several keys share the same value (example: keys 3 and 4 share the value 3) the results diverge, as here:

```py
x = {1: 2, 3: 3, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
```

Your code print:

```
dict_keys([1, 3, 4, 2, 0])
[4, 3, 1, 2, 0]
[3, 4, 1, 2, 0]
```

- In **s1** case, the dict is sorted on both values and keys so when 2 keys share a common value they are sorted too.
- In **s2** case only values are sorted. As sort algorithm is stable, when 2 keys  share the same value their relative order is kept in the result.